# Why I want to use Date() get Unix time but fail getHour()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

[image]

When I open this.setState, this bug will show up.
Hour and min are just two integers now, they do not hurt.

```
onChangeTime = (event) => {
    const time = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    let hour = parseInt(event.slice(0, 2),10);
    const min = parseInt(event.slice(3,5),10);
    if (min>20 && min<40){
      hour += 0.5
    } else if (min>40) {
      hour += 1
    }
    const departureTime = (hour - 6)*3600 + time
    this.setState({
      departureTime: departureTime
    });
  };
```

Comment: In dates.js you try to do a getHours() on a number and a number doesn't have a function property called getHours.

Comment: Your question is kind of confusing, maybe try to tell us what are you trying to achieve

1: Please share more of your source code so we can better understand the problem. 2: The error displayed in the image seems to be somewhere else in your code. 3. event probably doesn't have the data you are looking for... check the event.target.value.
4. if you are simply trying to get the mins and hours from the date... you could do: `new Date().getHours()` or `new Date().getMinutes()`

Comment: What are the value you are passing for  event  argument?

Comment: I find the source of problem, I am using react, and I store the Unix time in the state of React, when I hide the this.setState, it does not have bug, so I cannot store neither Unix time integer nor string format. Can anyone who knows react tell me why? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I recommended you to use `moment` is it will make you life easier

installation:

```
npm install moment --save   # npm 
//OR
yarn add moment             # Yarn
```

using:

```
const now = moment();
const hour = now.hour();
```

or

```
const hours = moment().format("hh")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I find the source of the problem, I am using react, and the thing is I cannot store Unix time in the state of React.